# USB debugging in Android studio is not working

Tags: android, debugging, usb

My Android emulator is terribly slow, So I connected my Android phone to Android studio and my device is showing. But when I click run, it shows **"Build failed"** in the catlog. Nothing happens on my phone. How to fix this?

Comment: *Build failed* doesn't seem like a device issue, but a build issue. Are you sure there isn't anything explaining the error?

Comment: Add the logcat where it says build failed

Comment: In the Build Output.., it shows "Build failed" and under that, it shows "Android resource linking failed" 19 times (19 errors)

Comment: Right. I fixed it by changing sdk version to 30 because my phone is Android 11. Thanks...!